# android загрузка EXCEL

Tags: android, excel

нашел в инете пример чтение excel. Вроде читает файлы, но есть один косяк. если сохраняю файл *.xlsx из libre office то он его не может прочитать. Если этот же файл просто открою обычным ms office или программой чтения эксель на телефоне и пересохраню, то все читает. использую LIBS: poi-3.12-android-a.jar и poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar. Может кто с таким сталкивался?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        Button bb= findViewById(R.id.button);
        bb.setOnClickListener(buttonOnclick);
    }

    View.OnClickListener buttonOnclick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tv.setText("");
            Intent PickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            PickerIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(PickerIntent, 1);
        }
    };

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String s="";
        if (requestCode==1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)  {
                Uri chosenUri = data.getData();
                String src = chosenUri.getPath();
                InputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream  = getContentResolver().openInputStream(chosenUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                    int rowsCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
                    for (int r = 0; r<rowsCount; r++) {
                        Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
                        int cellsCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
                        // Читаем содержимое одной строки за раз
                        for (int c = 0; c<cellsCount; c++)
                        {   // Преобразуем содержимое каждой сетки в строковую форму
                            String value = getCellAsString( row, c, formulaEvaluator);
                            s=s+value;
                            tv.setText(s);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* при чтении Libreoffice сюда выкидывает сразу*/
                }
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * Прочтите содержимое каждой строки в файле Excel
     * @param row
     * @param c
     * @param formulaEvaluator
     * @return
     */
    private static String getCellAsString(Row row, int c, FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator) {
        String value = "";
        try {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
            CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
            switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    value = ""+cellValue.getBooleanValue();
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    double numericValue = cellValue.getNumberValue();
                    if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        double date = cellValue.getNumberValue();
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
                        value = formatter.format(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(date));
                    } else {
                        value = ""+numericValue;
                    }
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    value = ""+cellValue.getStringValue();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            /* proper error handling should be here */
        }
        return value;
    };


}
```

Comment: выкидывает с ошибкой java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""  из ф-ции getCellAsString

Comment: В общем я тупанул. добавил try catch и все заработало  
                       String value="";            try {   value = getCellAsString(row, c, formulaEvaluator);  } catch (Exception e) {    e.printStackTrace();     }